# Managing file upload locations with http and https

Tags: file-uploads, config

I've got a file upload location that needs to serve files via http in the public part of the website, and serve files via https in the private part of the website and in the control panel (to avoid getting security warnings).

How can I handle this in EE?

Here's how I'm currently specifying file upload locations in the config.php file:

```
/* File Upload Preferences
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['upload_preferences'] = array(
  1 => array(
    'name'        => "Uploads",
    'server_path' => "${_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/uploads/",
    'url'         => "http://${_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/uploads/"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the protocol neutral implementation, so

```
/* File Upload Preferences
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['upload_preferences'] = array(
  1 => array(
    'name'        => "Uploads",
    'server_path' => "${_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/uploads/",
    'url'         => "//${_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/uploads/"
  )
);
```

Basically, this should allow either protocol to specified. The actually spec is called [**'Protocol-Relative'**](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) you can read about it.

IE6 have some issues with JS being loaded by URLs without protocol. And IE8- downloads css twice, if they don't have protocol. But you're fine to use them on images and other files.

This not work on EECMS 2.5.2, but [now it's fixed](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18210).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it wasn't working for me, but that was due to an CE Image bug (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-image/viewthread/9669) which was fixed today, so all is now well.